# How can I reset the connection between my laptop and my Nikon D5300?

Tags: nikon, linux, nikon-d5300

Using `gphoto2`/`gtkam`, I have managed to obtain a live view of my camera on my laptop. However, `gtkam` (or `digiKam`, for that matter) stops showing the live view once I have taken a picture. Further attempts at capturing an image just don't show a live view. If I toggle the camera on and off (while still connected to the laptop), the next attempt will show a live view, and then the cycle will continue. Toggling the camera is cumbersome; what options do I have from the laptop?

When I toggle the camera, I hear the sound of the shutter closing. I guess that indicates the camera is still active somehow - perhaps if I could stop it, I wouldn't need to turn it off. Removing and re-adding the camera from `gtkam` just errors out. The error is similar to [the `could not lock` error](http://gphoto.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/FAQ.html#FAQ-already-in-use) mentioned in the `gphoto2` documentation, but:

- AFAICT nothing other than `gtkam` is using the camera;
- the camera is sometimes listed in `gvfs-mount -l` output, but `gvfs-umount -s gphoto2` has no effect.

I'm using Arch Linux, kernel `4.2.5-1`.

Comment: I wonder if I should have posted this in [unix.se] instead.

Comment: You could both post it to Unix or to StackOverflow. Either way I recommend asking developers about that.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/645/8903 , although this may already be fixed. Patches for gphoto2 have been floating around for years.

Comment: It's not a programming question so don't ask at StackOverflow. Unix/Linux and Superuser would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try toggling the USB connection off and on. Maybe you also have to programmatically restart the program. Maybe this can help you pull it off:
https://www.linux.com/blog/disable-enable-usb-terminal

> First time, our modem must be plugged into our usb.  After that, we
>   trying to connect with wvdial command. Ups, I cannot got carrier.The
>   first solution for a long time is I pull out the modem from usb and
>   wait a few second than I plug again into usb. it's very make me feel
>   bored and angry. So, to fix the problem without do the really bad
>   clue. First time, You must open the terminal and make access as super
>   user : "sudo lsusb -t|less", this command will be give you list the
>   active usb. And in the result is :
>
> ```
>  /:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, class="root_hub", Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
>  /:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, class="root_hub", Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
>  /:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, class="root_hub", Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
>  |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, class="HID", Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
>  /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, class="root_hub", Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
>  |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, class="vend"., Driver=usbserial_generic, 12M
>  |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, class="vend"., Driver=usbserial_generic, 12M
>  |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 2, class="vend"., Driver=usbserial_generic, 12M
>  |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 3, class="stor"., Driver=usb-storage, 12M
>  |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, class="HID", Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
>  |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, class="HID", Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
>  /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, class="root_hub", Driver=ehci_hcd/8p, 480M
>  |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
>  |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
> ```
>
> After we know the actived usb that connect with our modem. Do this
>   command
>
> ```
> echo '2-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind # <- to make usb disable/turn off
> ```
>
> NB : `2-1` is the process that we will be kill. after you do that
>   command, the usb will be disable. Trying to dial again with wvdial. So
>   we have the result:
>
> ```
> eject: unable to find or open device for: `/dev/sr0'
> --> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.60
> --> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
> --> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
> --> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> *This is good information.That's have mean, the usb succesfully set as disable. We do again the command such as step number 5 but with
>   different input at the end. So ,like this:
>
> ```
> echo '2-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind # <- to make usb active again // the different command just in the end of syntax. NB :
> ```
>
> `2-1` is process that will be make enable. Try again with the wvdial
>   command like as before. And.... i no need to pull out and plug in
>   again modem in usb. So, the mainly command is in step 5 and 7.

One more possibility would be to use darktable. It uses the same backend, but perhaps has some better trickery regarding the commands that are sent to the camera:
https://www.linux.com/learn/how-remote-control-your-camera-darktable-linux

Comment: +1, hopefully this helps someone else, but my D5300 long since completely stopped responding to the USB cable (on both Linux and Windows). I just use a card reader now. :/